# How to fetch query results which don't have a join match in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

How can I query a table and only return results in which the joined table has no records?

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't appear to work:

```
SELECT a.* FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON b.aid = a.id
AND b.id IS NULL
WHERE a.status = 1
```

This doesn't seem to work for some reason. I'm trying to avoid sub queries due to performance reasons.

Comment: `b.id IS NULL` needs to be in the `WHERE`clause not in the `ON` clause

Comment: Swap the last two lines around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON b.aid = a.id
WHERE a.status = 1 AND b.id IS NULL
```

As mentioned in the comment, `outer join` and `join` keywords are identical in MySQL.
However, moving the `b.id` null check to the `WHERE` clause WILL make a difference (effectively making the check after the join, not as part of the join).

To explain, in your code, the database is checking for a row in `TableB` that has an `AID` column value that matches the current row in `TableA`, AND an `ID` column value of `null`. As this will probably never match (assuming you have no rows in `TableB` with a `null` value for the `ID` column), you'll have no data coming back from `TableB` (every single column will be null).

In my code, the database is checking for a row in `TableB` that has an `AID` column value that matches the `id` column of the current row in `TableA`, and only if it doesn't find a match, it'll return `null` for every column in `TableB` FOR THAT ROW in `tableA`.
Then, once it's done that, it checks the combined data to find any rows where the `b.id` column is `null`... effectively only returning rows that exist in `TableA` that don't have a corresponding (matched) row in `TableB`

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN. OUTER keyword is optional in SQL

Comment: Yes, but you've accidentally hit on the correct answer anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You need OUTER JOIN: See the all JOINS:

[image]